# How to get the exact exception of attempted jobs in laravel?

Tags: laravel, exception, notifications, queue, jobs

I have a Notification class with the retryUntil method. when an exception occurs through the code or from the notification server, it tries until appointed time then fails the job with **MaxAttemptsExceededException** (that logs into the exception field of the database)

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: Modules\Insurance\Notifications\IssuePolicyInsuredNotif has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.
```

```
class InstallmentReminderNotif extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public $backoff = 20;

    protected $message;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [SmsChannel::class];
    }

    public function retryUntil(): \DateTime
    {
        return now()->addMinute();
    }
}
```

I want it to save every exact exception of each try instead of MaxAttemptsExceededException

Answer (score 0):

Add a `failed()` method to receive the exception that caused the job to fail as its argument. You can then log this exception or handle it as you wish.

```
public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    // Log the exception or save it to the database
    Log::error($exception->getMessage());
}
```